# Is there a 'cleaner' way I can assign a MySQL value to a jQuery variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am creating a basic auction site and having a slight issue where when a bid is placed, it sometimes says it's too low, despite it being higher than the current bid. I think this is to do with the way I am getting the current bid, as it's not a very tidy approach in my opinion.

So my HTML/PHP which retrieves and lists the auctions on the page:

```
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * From auction WHERE category = 'Bathroom' ORDER BY ID DESC");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo "<form name='auction' id='auction" . $row['ID'] . "'>
            <input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $row['ID'] . "' />
            <div class='auction-thumb'>
                <div class='auction-name'>" . $row['Item'] . "</div>";
            echo "<img class='auction' src='" . $row['ImagePath'] . "' />";
            echo "<div class='auction-bid'>Current Bid: £<div class='nospace' id='" . $row['ID'] . "'>" . $row['CurrentBid'] . "</div></div>";
            echo "<div class='auction-bid'>Your Name: <input type='text' class='bidder' name='bidname' autocomplete='off'/></div>";
            echo "<div class='auction-bid'>Your Bid: <input type='text' class='auction-text' name='bid' autocomplete='off'/></div>";
            echo "<div class='auction-bid'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Place Bid!' /></div>";
            echo "<div class='bid-success' id='bid" . $row['ID'] . "'>Bid placed!</div>";
    echo "</div></form>";
```

As you can see, I wrap the column/value "CurrentBid" in a div with the ID of the ID in MySQL.

Then when someone places a bid, the following jQuery/AJAX code is called:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form[name="auction"]').submit(function(){
            var id = $(this).find('input[name="id"]').val();
            var bidname = $(this).find('input[name="bidname"]').val();
            var bid = $(this).find('input[name="bid"]').val();
            var currentbid = $('#'+id).text();

            var itemdesc = $(this).find('.auction-name').text();

            if (bidname == '')
            {
                alert("No name!")
                return false;   
            }

            if (bid > currentbid)
            {
                alert("Bid is greater than current bid");   
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Bid is too low!");
                return false;   
            }

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "auction-handler.php",
            data: {bidname: bidname, bid: bid, id: id, itemdesc: itemdesc},
            success: function(data){
                $('#bid'+id).fadeIn('slow', function () {
                    $(this).delay(1500).fadeOut('slow');
                });
            }
        });
        return false;

        }); 
    });
```

As you can see from this code, I assign the variable 'currentbid' by selecting the ID of the div container, and then pulling through the text within it.

I am not sure if this is what is causing me the problem, but it seems likely, I cannot figure out why sometimes it says "Bid too low" despite me putting in a higher price then what is currently in the Current Bid div.

Ideally, I'd like to assign the jQuery variable 'currentbid' with the value directly from MySQL, but I am not too sure if this is possible.

Does anyone know of a way that I can do this? Or is there a better way I can assign a value to the variable?

Thank you

Comment: As you give if() {} else {} condition, if your first time condition is false then it shows alert message of 'Bid is too low!'. Another code is not executable. Please check your condition first, and be clear which logic you want to do.

Comment: 1) use `parseFloat()` to make sure you're comparing numbers. 2) don't do your checks in JS! Instead do your checks on the server, so the user can not manipulate them.

Comment: `Ideally, I'd like to assign the jQuery variable 'currentbid' with the value directly from MySQL, but I am not too sure if this is possible` It is, either by injecting JSON into the html-markup or by an ajax-request. Is this some kind of educational project, or do you want to use this code on some real user? Because from a usability-standpoint this is horrible 90's code.

Comment: I am still learning the ropes. Ideally I'd like to know the best way of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing strings now instead of numeric values. You should cast your values to floats before comparing.

```
bid = parseFloat(bid)
currentbid = parseFloat(currentbid);
```

Also on the server side when processing to bid you should first check the currentBid from the database because it could have changed already.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. This seems to be working now. Although, the problem was a bit random so if it does happen again I will let you know. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please accept the anwser if it has solved your problem

Comment: Yes I was just waiting for the timer.

Comment: Ah... didn't realise. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I need the bid and currentbid as floats with 2 decimal places rather than round numbers, but doing so causes the error to happen again where it says the bid is too low. Do you have any ideas? `bid = parseFloat(bid).toFixed(2); currentbid = parseFloat(currentbid).toFixed(2);`

Comment: toFixed converts the number to a string. So you are reversing the parseFloat. You can wrap it in a parseFloat again:
parseFloat( parseFloat(bid).toFixed(2) );